# Search through Array in data objects

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I've no python experience, How can I condense so It's flexible for array length ?

basically I like to manually freeze objects(Disable Selection), I've got that working perfect, now I just need to Unfreeze all objects in one click.

Instead of that code smell, how can I check array.length using Python?

anything like this ?

**for object in data.objects
object.hide_select = False**

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in bpy.data.objects:
    item.hide_select = False
```